# pack and unpack to switch from function taking array of argumento to variadic function and viceversa

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, lodash, variadic-functions

I've just been wandering why lodash/fp doesn't have these two functions:

```
unpack = f => x => f(...x)
pack = f => (...x) => f(x)
```

I'm borrowing the name `unpack` from the function [`boost::hana::unpack`](http://boostorg.github.io/hana/group__group-_foldable.html#ga7b0c23944364ce61136e10b978ae2170) provided by the C++ library [Boost.Hana](http://boostorg.github.io/hana/).

In my C++ programming experience, I've used `unpack` a gazillion times, so I was wandering how comes nobody needs it in JavaScript.

Or maybe Lodash has such a function and I just can't guess the name?

Comment: Unpack is [spread](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#spread)., and pack is [rest](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#rest)

Comment: @OriDrori, as short as it might be, I think you could make it an answer.